# ip:port node list for testnet?

Tags: nodes

https://blockchain.info/ip-log

shows the ip:port for bitcoin nodes

where can I find nodes for testnet?

Google is coming up dry!

After many hours spent; I tried what seemed the logical approach: use a main-net nodes ip but change the port from 8333 to 8332 (but, no luck, not connecting to testnet!)

also tried 18332   :/

I am a new company, I want to test!

---

I am using this https://github.com/sebicas/bitcoin-sniffer to realize new-transactions and new-blocks real time on main-net but I am failing to do so on testnet (where do I connect? please)

This information should be instantly available and easy to find!

Then we wonder why bitcoin is not adopted!

The information is no where on the net!!

While literally the whole planet (99% of everyone) is a newbie (why is this not readily accessible info!??)

I am at a loss for words ...

---

I currently connect successfully to bitcoin main-net using:

{host:'109.123.116.24',port:8333}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash


for i in testnet-seed.bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch \
    seed.tbtc.petertodd.org \
    testnet-seed.bluematt.me \
    testnet-seed.bitcoin.schildbach.de
do
    nslookup $i 2>&1 | grep Address | cut -d' ' -f2
done
```

Testnet is port 18333 by default. Or run a testnet node and check what it connects to.